# Sagemaker ThrottlingException when calling the ListTrainingJobs

Tags: boto3, amazon-sagemaker

While running multiple training jobs simultaneously using operator, I am getting below error. Any recommendations.

```
**Error**
 An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the ListTrainingJobs operation

Operator used to call training .
**from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.sagemaker import SageMakerTrainingOperator**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the [`check_interval` property on the operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/sagemaker_training_operator/index.html) to avoid throttling, or request a rate limit increase for ListTrainingJobs from the [Service Quotas console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)